# How is Barry still alive in the 22nd century?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

I am new to the whole Flash story, but I need help understanding something regarding the Flash and Reverse Flash. So if Eobard Thawne is a distant relative to Eddie, does that mean Barry doesn't age? Because from the looks of it Eobard Thawne is a bit older and from a further future. I mean, surely in the timeline Eobard is from Barry should be dead of old age?

The Reverse Flash even said that Cisco has been dead for centuries to him. Could someone explain this for me?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask here. Why would Barry not age if Eobard is Eddie's relative? You might want to look at [Does the Flash age?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/125086/70236)

Comment: CWhat I am asking is that if Eobard Thawne is a distant relative to Eddie. How Can the flash still be Alive in 22 centuries? Eddie and the flash is from 2015 where as the reverse flash is from 2151 in the future.

Answer (score 7):

Thawne is not just a "distant relative", but actually a descendant of Eddie Thawne. While Eobard Thawne is from a distant future, he and Barry both have the ability to run through time. Due to the nature of time-travel, alteration of the timeline, and paradoxes, it's unclear exactly when or how Barry and Thawne originally met. Barry has traveled through time to prevent/ensure events before, and will likely do so again. Similarly, Thawne has traveled through time for his own purposes, where he may have encountered Barry at many points.

We have no conclusive proof whether or not Barry ages visibly in the Arrowverse, but we know that the rules of time are different for him due to his connection with the Speed Force.

Comment: Alright. Good to know I haven't missed something that explains exactly how all this is connected. I just assumed that maybe Barry ended up having grandchildren and that one got discovered his/her identity. And thus Eobard did some research and travelled back to Barry to kill him so that the flash wouldn't get any kids and that way no flash in the future

Answer (score -2):

Flash has the ability, at a microscopic level, to move fast (really very fast) and also has the incredible ability to heal (as shown in episodes where he has healed several fractures in hours) very quickly.

This would mean that he can't grow old, as Flash will constantly heal himself at a cellular level. Also, he has co-founded the Justice League, an organisation for fighting crime way into the future, which means he is alive and running in the future, which basically means he's immortal other than the fact he can die from an injury.

Comment: Agree that it's established that Barry heals fast. I don't see how any of the rest of your answer follows from that.